# MySQL: Count of Maximum Occurrences of Distinct Value

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having a problem with an aggregate function in mysql.
As an example I have this table layout. It gets filled with data every x minutes.

```
Company | Employee | Room | Temperature
---------------------------------------
A       | Mike     | 301  | 20
A       | Mike     | 301  | 30
A       | Mike     | 301  | 30
A       | Mike     | 402  | 40
A       | Lisa     | 402  | 10
```

Now in my query I'm grouping Company + Employee into one result and I'm looking for the count of the maximum occurrences of the Room value while still aggregating other values like temperature.

```
SELECT
    Company,
    Employee,
    ??? as Room,
    AVG(Temperature) as Temperature
FROM
    example_table
GROUP BY
    Company,
    Employee
```

In this example the room 301 appears 3 times for Mike which should output 3 in the aggregate function. Since the data is on a set interval it is basically the maximum length of a stay in a room for this employee. I'm looking for a result like this

```
Company | Employee | Room | Temperature
---------------------------------------
A       | Mike     | 3    | 30
A       | Lisa     | 1    | 10
```

I feel like I'm missing something but so far I have found nothing which worked in a query for me. I can group_concant the rooms and solve this with 2 lines of code in php, but the actual data is gigabytes which I don't want to send to a script. Performance of the database query doesn't matter. MySQL 8 is available.

edit: I've changed the example to make sure `COUNT(DISTINCT Room)` doesn't accidentally give the correct result, because it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You will need to aggregate the counts on (company, employee, room) separately, and then take the max of those by (company, employee). It's helps that your final results don't actually care which room though, that can get complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Company, Employee
   , MAX(roomOccurrence) AS Room
   , AVG(roomTemp * roomOccurrence) AS Temperature
FROM ( SELECT Company, Employee, Room
          , COUNT(*) AS roomOccurrence, AVG(Temperature) AS roomTemp
       FROM example_table
       GROUP BY Company, Employee, Room
     ) AS subQ
GROUP BY Company, Employee
;
```

Note the outer temperature average weights the temperature average from the inner query.

*Alternatively, you could SUM the temps in the subquery...and then divide the SUM of the SUM by the SUM of the room COUNT; but's it should be the same either way. I would at best expect minor performance differences, and not sure if either way would be consistently faster.*